# why my Python recursive function not working?

Tags: python, function

Hey everyone hope you all doing great!
I was practicing my python, I write a code to execute the factorials of the given Number but the code didn't execute!

The code

```
def factorial_recursive(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 0:
        return 1
        return n * factorial_recursive(n-1)

f = factorial_recursive(5)
print(f)
```

After running Python File: None

where the answer must be 120 as factorial of 5 is 120

Comment: Please check your indentation.  Two `return`s in a row is definitely wrong, but it's possible that something got messed up when you pasted your code into the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have your second return statement indented in the if statement. The second return should be for any other cases. Here is the correct function:

```py
def factorial_recursive(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 0: 
        return 1
    return n * factorial_recursive(n-1)

f = factorial_recursive(5)
print(f)
```

Outputs: 120

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function like so:

```
f=factorial_recursive(4)
print(f)
```

If you actually want to use it on some number (like 4).

Also, you should learn to format your code on stack overflow. Makes it easy for others to understand your code.